# Running fsck on internal disk which also has ecryptfs encrypted folder

Tags: encryption, ecryptfs, fsck

I could not google out straight answer to this.

My laptops hard disk is **not** encrypted. Within my un-encrypted home folder, I have a Personal folder which is encrypted using ecryptfs. I followed mainly [this tutorial](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-create-a-private-encrypted-folder-on-ubuntu-810-intrepid.html)

I know that if I have LUKS partition (as I have on my external USB), I must not run fsck directly on the disk, It must be run as

```
 fsck -M /dev/mapper/luks-4c6...
```

But what about the ecryptfs folder. Since its a stacked file system, I really don't have control over skipping this folder when checking the hard disk. My doubts are

- Would fsck ing the hard disk mess up ecryptfs folder(s)
- Assuming answer as no to above, would fsck skip this folder (but then how would fsck really know anything about whats on top of the file
  system).
- On the other hand, how do I ensure that the ecryptfs
  folders dont get corrupted. (Some times I do forget to unmount while
  shutting down the PC).
- Or unlike LUKS, I do not need to worry about fsck ing individual
  containers in ecryptfs. fscking the underlying container is good
  enough and supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fsck` checks the underlying, physical, blocks-on-disk filesystem. It **Must** do this when nobody else is accessing the disk (single-user, Live boot). At that time, your encrypted folder is not mounted, therefore not visible, except as blocks-on-disk of binary data with really silly filenames (do a `ls` of the `.Private/` subdirectory to see what I mean). It's only when you have logged in, and `mount`ed your `ecryptfs` folder that it is decrypted, and can be said to "exist". So in order, the answers to your multiple questions are:

No.

That folder cannot be said to "exist" at `fsck` time.

Since the encrypted folder is `mount`ed, and appears in `/etc/mtab`, it will be "handled" when you do a polite shutdown (`sudo shutdown`, or `shut down` from the `Log out` menu. If you just kill power, or halt the VM, you will corrupt your encrypted (and non-encrypted) filesystems, eventually, due to updated disk meta information in RAM not being written to "disk". `fsck` may then detect (and offer to "fix") problems with the underlying, physical, blocks-on-disk filesystem, which *could* trash the encrypted filesystem. Do polite shutdowns.

The filesystems you are worrying about have not been created at `fsck` time.

Comment: So as long as every time I have done a polite shutdown and then run a fsck    it will not impact encrypted folder  (would there be any point in runing fsck ? at this stage )  I would want to run fsck on the disk especially, say due to a bug I have to force shut the laptop. Now at this stage since I also had a unmounted encryted folder, I would run a risk of  trashing the encrypted folder.

Comment: No more than the "risk" that `fsck` will harm any file/folder. That is, very, very, very low, not not zero.  Yes, the underlying blocks-on-the-disk filesystem provides the actual data that `ecryptfs` decrypts and presents as a filesystem. Because the blocks-on-disk are magnetic wiggles living in the Real World, they're affected by Real World events. If `ecryptsfs` tries to read a block of data to decrypt, but can't, due to underlying blocks-on-disk errors, nobody will be happy. The blocks-on-disk filesystem is the one you should `fsck`. The `ecryptfs` filesystem is made up  by software.